# Convert Evaluation to Volume

Tags: windows-server-2016

On 2016/10/12 (yesterday), as Microsoft's TechNet article "[Evaluation Versions and Upgrade Options for Windows Server 2012](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574204(v=ws.11).aspx)" suggested that it's relatively straight-forward to convert from evaluation to production, I downloaded the ISO for the evaluation version of Windows Server 2016 Standard from the [Technet Evaluation Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-technical-preview), installed it, connected it to our Active Directory domain, and promoted it to be the second domain controller.

On 2016/10/13 (today), Windows Server 2016 was released (I knew I should have waited).

I logged into our Volume Licensing Service Center, obtained our SPLA product key and tried to activate which failed.

As advised by https://msfreaks.wordpress.com/2016/10/06/convert-windows-server-2016-evaluation-to-licensed/, I executed command `dism /online /set-edition:ServerStandard /productkey:WC2BQ-8NRM3-FDDYY-2BFGV-KHKQY /accepteula` to convert from Windows Server 2016 Standard Evaluation to Windows Server 2016 Standard which completed successfully.

I executed command `dism /online /set-edition:ServerStandard /productkey:<our SPLA product key> /accepteula` which failed and outputted the following:

> Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool Version: 10.0.14393.0
>
> Image Version: 10.0.14393.0
>
> Error: 50
>
> This Windows image cannot upgrade to the edition of Windows that was
>   specified. The upgrade cannot proceed. Run the /Get-TargetEditions
>   option to see what edition of Windows you can upgrade to.
>
> The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log

I executed command `slmgr /ipk <our SPLA product key>` which completed successfully.

Windows Activation is now reporting the following:

> Windows
>
> Edition       Windows Server 2016 Standard
>
> Activation    Windows is not activated Product ID 00377-70126-37251-AA898
>
> Product Key XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-Y4HYC
>
> We can’t activate Windows on this device because you don't have a
>   valid digital licence or product key. Go to the Store to buy genuine
>   Windows. Error code: 0xC004F012

[image]

Comment: Obviously it worked for you (as per answer) but it shouldn't of done for a couple of reasons. The first guide you linked to, you also shouldn't be able to do this on a domain controller at all. The second guide is KMS and depends on a KMS being configured and setup correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh..

I selected "Troubleshoot" just to see what would happen and Windows has activated..

> Windows
>
> Edition Windows Server 2016 Standard
>
> Activation Windows is activated
>
> Product ID 00377-70126-37251-AA898
>
> Product Key XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-Y4HYC

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The 2012 way of converting works just fine
to check the current version from an elevated command prompt type

```
slmgr.vbs /dlv
```

or

```
DISM /online /Get-CurrentEdition
```

available versions:

```
DISM /online /Get-TargetEditions
example:
Target Edition : ServerStandard
Target Edition : ServerDatacenter
```

to change the version:

```
DISM /online /Set-Edition:<edition ID> /ProductKey:XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX /AcceptEula
```

example:

```
DISM /online /Set-Edition:ServerStandard /ProductKey:XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX /AcceptEula
```

source:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574204(v=ws.11).aspx